# Union по двум полям нескольких таблиц, с выводом остальных полей

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Есть таблицы с одинаковым полями следующего типа:

```
name: table_1
_________________________________________
|pole_1   | pole_2  | pole_3  | pole_4  |
-----------------------------------------
| 1       |  1      |   1     |     1   | - уникальная запись
| 2       |  2      |   2     |     2   | - уникальная запись
| 3       |  3      |   3     |     3   | - уникальная запись
-----------------------------------------
```

```
name: table_2
_________________________________________
|pole_1   | pole_2  | pole_3  | pole_4  |
-----------------------------------------
|  1      |   1     |   1     |   1     | - запись уже есть в table_1
|  1      |   2     |   3     |   4     | - уникальная запись
----------------------------------------
```

```
name: table_3
_________________________________________
|pole_1   | pole_2  | pole_3  | pole_4  |
-----------------------------------------
|   2     |   2     |   2     |    2    | - запись уже есть в table_1
|   3     |   4     |   5     |    6    | - уникальная запись
-----------------------------------------
```

```
....
```

```
name: table_10
_________________________________________
|pole_1   | pole_2  | pole_3  | pole_4  |
-----------------------------------------
|  3      |   4     |   5     |   6     | - запись уже есть в table_3
|  7      |   8     |   10    |   12    | - уникальная запись
----------------------------------------
```

Нужно сделать вывод всех уникальных записей, со всеми полями, со всех таблиц по **двум** полям, в порядке `table_1, table_2, table_3,..,table_10`.

Делаю следующие:

```
    select pole_1, pole_2 from ( -- c GROUP BY могу указать только 2 поля, а нужно на вывод все 4 (pole_1, pole_2, pole_3, pole_4)
         select * from (
             select t.*, 1 as table_number from table_1 t
             union all
             select t.*, 2 as table_number from table_2 t
             union all
             select t.*, 3 as table_number from table_3 t
             union all
             ....
             union all
             select t.*, 10 as table_number from table_10 t
         ) order by table_number
    ) group by pole_1, pole_2
```

Получаю записи, которые мне и нужны, но как теперь вывести оставшиеся поля (`pole_3, pole_4`), чтобы в результате получить таблицу исходного вида:

```
name: result_table (Таблица которая должна быть на выходе)
_________________________________________
|pole_1   | pole_2  | pole_3  | pole_4  |
-----------------------------------------
| 1       |  1      |   1     |     1   | - Запись взята именно из table_1
| 2       |  2      |   2     |     2   | - Запись взята именно из table_1
| 3       |  3      |   3     |     3   | - Запись взята именно из table_1
| 1       |  2      |   3     |     4   | - Запись взята именно из table_2
| 3       |  4      |   5     |     6   | - Запись взята именно из table_3
| 7       |  8      |   10    |     12  | - Запись взята именно из table_10
-----------------------------------------
```

Таблицы имеют приоритет по мере убывания, т.е. самый высокий **приоритет** у таблицы `table_1`, **из которой нужна брать записи в первую очередь**. Самый низкий **приоритет** у `table_10`, **записи из неё берутся в последнюю очередь**, если в других таблицах одинаковых записей обнаружено не было.

**ВАЖНО:** Поля не используемые в `group by` могут отличаться, поэтому и необходим приоритет.

Comment: Непонятно - от слова "совсем". Если показанный запрос (кстати, слишком усложнённый, простого `select pole_1, pole_2 from table_1 union select ... union select pole_1, pole_2 from table_10` достаточно) возвращает уникальные пары, то попытка добавить остальные поля снова "размножит" эти пары. Попробуйте показать на примере, что ли, 2-3 таблиц по 3-4 записи хватит для понимания ситуации имхо.

Comment: а если так и указать `select pole_1, pole_2, pole_3, pole_4..`?

Comment: @azlov c group by такое не работает

Comment: @Akina обычный union не гарантирует, что выборка будет происходить сначала из первой таблицы, потом из второй, затем из третий. Смысл как раз в том, что необходимо получить уникальные записи, по всем таблицам, но со всеми полями.

Comment: Не говорите глупостей. Ваш ORDER BY в подзапросе без LIMIT будет сервером тупо проигнорирован. Но даже если бы и нет - GROUP BY тоже чхал на исходный порядок записей. Но даже если на секунду представить, что всё учтётся - какая в пень разница, из какой таблицы упало значение? Главное - что выведено. Да и всё равно информации об этом в выходном наборе нет.

Comment: @Akina смысл определенного порядка таблиц в том, что поля которые НЕ используются в GROUP BY могут отличаться и это очень критично для данного запроса. т.е. если есть запись в table_1 должна попасть именно она иначе из table_2, иначе из table_3 и так далее.

Comment: *и это очень критично для данного запроса* Абсолютно некритично. Во-первых, для результата - он при любом порядке будет один и тот же. Во-вторых, для порядка выполнения - он довольно нечасто соответствует тексту, а в данном случае вообще может быть распараллелен, и уж тогда какой нафиг вообще порядок...

Comment: И вопрос - что в приоритете? просто решение проблемы? или решение наиболее эффективно? или наименее затратно? или что-то ещё?

Comment: @Akina в приоритете получить необходимы набор данных. Любым способ. Данный Sql был как пример, хода моих мыслей, если есть другой способ, буду рад им воспользоваться. Если есть возможность сделать это ещё и быстро будет просто супер.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю до группировки уже заменить значения в колонках `pole_3` и `pole_4` на требуемое. Первое, при сортировке по `table_number` и группировке по `pole_1, pole2`. А после этого уже сгруппируем по всем полям, что бы убрать дубликаты строк. Замену значений будем производить оконной функцией [first_value](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm#SQLRF00642):

```
select pole_1, pole_2, pole_3, pole_4
  from (select pole_1, pole_2,
               first_value(pole_3) over(partition by pole_1, pole_2 order by table_number) pole_3,
               first_value(pole_3) over(partition by pole_1, pole_2 order by table_number) pole_4
           from (
             select t.*, 1 as table_number from table_1 t
             union all
             select t.*, 2 as table_number from table_2 t
             union all
             select t.*, 3 as table_number from table_3 t
             union all
             ....
             union all
             select t.*, 10 as table_number from table_10 t
         )
    )
  group by pole_1, pole_2, pole_3, pole_4
```

---

Второй вариант - пронумеровать строки в пределах будущей группы и взять первые:

```
select pole_1, pole_2, pole_3, pole_4
  from (select pole_1, pole_2, pole_3, pole_4
               row_number() over(partition by pole_1, pole_2 order by table_number) RN
           from (
             select t.*, 1 as table_number from table_1 t
             union all
             ....
           )
    )
  where RN=1
```

Comment: @Akina Вы видимо имели ввиду MINUS, потому как в oracle нет EXCEPT. Кроме того он сверяет все поля и когда значение pole_3 будет отличаться то и запись в результат попадет. Значит select * использовать нельзя. А без полей 3 и 4 мы получим только факт того, что запись надо брать из этой таблицы. Так что все таки придется переписать на not exists например. Но в эффективности такого решения я очень сильно сомневаюсь, одну и ту же запись t1 придется искать до 9 раз и по факту надо будет по индексу найти почти _все_ записи таблицы t1. Но конечно окончательное решение может дать только эксперимент

Comment: Просто меня сильно смущает эта сортировка промежуточного совокупного набора... хотя да, куда от него деваться.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, оч крутое решение, начал проверять сейчас, но почему то пару раз из 100 выдало решение из таблички table_1, хотя должно было взять из table_1

Comment: @AlexKnow Без group by сделайте общий order by pole_1, pole_2, table_number и посмотрите данные, сами поля 3,4 и что дают first_value. Может поймете в чем проблема. по логике ошибаться запрос не может, скорее всего что то не заметили

Comment: @Mike да скорее всего моя ошибка, хотел спросить, а что лучше, общий ордер бай для всех UNION ALL или всё же лучше сортировать каждое поле 'first_value(pole_3) over(partition by pole_1, pole_2 order by table_number) pole_3. как здесь если этих полей станет много.

Comment: @AlexKnow Оптимизатор у oracle достаточно умный и одинаковые over выполняет только один раз.

Comment: @AlexKnow Для большого количества полей придумал другой вариант, смотрите

Comment: @Mike круто, получается. это да же без GROUP BY? афигеть и работает быстро

Comment: @Mike Решение просто пушка